# p-th power roots of unity of quotient of $R/p^n$ are principal units.

Tags: solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $R$ be a $p$-adically complete local ring with valuation $v_R$ and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_R = \{ x \in R \mid v_R(x) > 0\}$.
Then we have its quotient ring $R/p^n$.

How can I show that $\mu_{p^\infty}(R/p^n) = (1 + \mathfrak{m}_R)/p^n$?

Here for a ring $S$, I mean $\mu_{p^\infty}(S) = \varinjlim_{k \geq 1} \mu_{p^k}(S)
= \{ x \in S \mid \exists k \geq 1 \text{ such that } x^{p^k} = 1\}$.

My attempt:
For '$\supset$': suppose $1 + x \in (1 + \mathfrak{m}_R)/p^n$.
Then $v_R(x) > 0$ and we can define $N := \max(\log_p\left(\frac{v_R(p^n)}{v_R(x)}\right),n)$.
Then for $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq N}$ we have $p^k \geq p^N \geq \frac{v_R(p^n)}{v_R(x)}$ hence $v_R(x^{p^k}) \geq v_R(p^n)$ which means $x^{p^k} = a p^n$ for some $a \in R$
and $x^{p^k} = 0$ in $R/p^n$.

Also we have in $R/p^n$ that $(1+x)^{p^k} = 1 + x^{p^k}$ because $k \geq n$, so $(1+x)^{p^k} = 
1 + x^{p^k} = 1$ in $R/p^n$, which means $1+x \in \mu_{p^k}(R/p^n) \subset \mu_{p^\infty}(R/p^n)$.

For '$\subset$': suppose $x \in \mu_{p^\infty}(R/p^n)$, so $x^{p^k} = 1$ for some $k \geq 1$. We may assume that $k \geq n$.
Then $(x-1)^{p^k} = x^{p^k} -1 = 0$ in $R/p^n$ which means $(x-1)^{p^k} = a p^n$  for some $a \in R$. Then $v_R(x-1)= \frac{v_R( a p^n)}{p^k} \geq \frac{n}{p^k} v_R(p) > 0$ so $x-1 \in \mathfrak{m}_R$, which means $x = 1 + (x-1) \in 1 + \mathfrak{m}_R$.

Comment: You’re using several times the claim that if $k \geq n$, then in $R/(p^n)$, $(x-1)^{p^k}=x^{p^k}-1$. Could you prove it (say, if $p>2$ – it’s false if $p=2$ but the approach should be fixable)? If that’s true, your proof is correct.

Comment: But that claim seems false: consider the ring of integers of a sufficiently ramified extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ with $p>3$ and assume that $x$ has valuation (normalized so that $v(p)=1$) $\nu >0$ such that $2p\nu > 1$ and $p\nu < 1$ (so $p^2\nu > 2$). Then it seems that $(1+x)^{p^2}$ is congruent to $1+\binom{p^2}{p}x^p \neq 1$ mod $p^2$, while $x^{p^2}$ is zero mod $p^2$.

Comment: @ThePhoenix thank you for the proof idea. Do you know a proof when the valuation of $R$ is not necessarily discrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how I would do it. For $\subset$, $R/m_R$ is a field of characteristic $p$, so only $1$ is a $p^n$-th root of unity for any $n$. Thus $\mu_{p^{\infty}}(R/(p^n))$ must map to $1$ under reduction mod $m_R$, QED.

For $\supset$, normalize $v_R$ so that $v_R(p)=1$. Let $x =1+y \in 1+m_R$. Then $\Phi_{p^k}(x)=\Phi_p(x^{p^{k-1}})$ is congruent to $\Phi_p(1)=p$ mod $y$, and therefore $v_R(\Phi_{p^k}(x))\geq\min(1,v_R(y))$.

Therefore, if $k \geq 1$, $v_R(x^{p^k}-1) =v_R(y)+ \sum_{1 \leq l \leq k}{v_R(\Phi_{p^l}(x))} \geq v_R(y)+k\min(1,v_R(y))$.

So for large enough $k$, $x^{p^k}$ is congruent to $1$ mod $p^n$, and $x \in \mu_{p^{\infty}}(R/(p^n))$.

Comment: Thank you, what is the map $\Phi_{p^\ell}$? Is it the lift of the Frobenius on $R/\mathfrak{m}_R$ to $R/p^n$? If so, why is $\Phi_p(1) = p \bmod y$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, $\Phi_t$ here is the $t$-th cyclotomic polynomial.